# Select Distinct columns from table JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I was wondering if there was a way using JPA query (not sure what the word I'm looking for is sorry).

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {


    List<User> findByLastNameIgnoreCase(String lastName); //This is the format I am looking for

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT t.lastName FROM User t") //Don't want to have to use the @Query 
    List<String> findDistinctLastNames();

}
```

Hopefully that makes it more clear. But I am trying to perform that Query without having to use the @Query. It doesn't really affect anything having it there, I would just like it. Is that statement possible?

Comment: I think you missed the `by` in `findDistinctByLastNames`

Comment: No I've tried with `findDistinctByLastName` as well. I don't want a List of Users returned or to pass a parameter in. I'm simply trying to get the Distinct String contents from the column `lastNames`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA uses reflection to match method signatures to field names and operations so confirming you have the correct column name would be a good place to start, i.e. is it `lastName` or `lastNames`?

Otherwise, according to the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), the following should work correctly:

```
List<User> findDistinctByLastName(String lastName);
```

Are you getting a stack trace?